# solving a third-order nonlinear ordinary differential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve:

$$\left (\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} \right)^{2}+\frac{d^{3}y}{dy^{3}} \frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not to start with $y'=z$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: try to find such expression that it is a product of $y(x)$ derivatives and derivative of this expression w.r.t. $x$ is a L.H.S. of equation.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Do you see that left part of equation is just a $\frac{d}{dx}(y' \cdot y'')$ ?

Comment: OK, very thanks.