# solving third-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve:

$(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}})^2+\frac{d^{3}y}{dx^{3}} \frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(y'')^2+y^{'''}y'=0$$
after substitution $v=y'$ we get
$$(v')^2+v''v=0$$
$$\frac{v'}{v}=-\frac{v''}{v'}$$
after integration
$$\log v = -\log v' + C_1$$
$$v = \frac{C_2}{v'}$$
$$vv'=C_2$$
$$(v^2)'=2C_2$$
$$v^2=2C_2x+C_3$$
$$y'=v=\pm\sqrt{C_4x+C_3}$$
So
$$y(x) = \pm\int \sqrt{C_4x+C_3}\, dx$$

Comment: see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080451/solving-a-third-order-nonlinear-ordinary-differential/1080477?noredirect=1#comment2199131_1080477), please. Why are not the answers equal?

Comment: Now, if $(\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}})^{2}+\frac{d^{3}y}{dx^{3}}\frac{dy}{dx}=d$ that $d>0$, what?

Comment: @user: in [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080451/solving-a-third-order-nonlinear-ordinary-differential/1080477?noredirect=1#comment2199131_1080477) solution there is a mistake, (you can easily check that $x^2$ is not a solution for your eqution, while it is in the answers example). For the second comment, you should use Evgeny's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080451/solving-a-third-order-nonlinear-ordinary-differential/1080477?noredirect=1#comment2199131_1080477)

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot.

Comment: Add $\pm$ at the end.

Comment: @Did: thanks for the comment.